# Java - Scroll down to specific line in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, anchor, jtextpane, caret

I am working on a program that has a `JTextPane` that holds a large document that the user can edit, and the document has links so that a person can jump to different parts of the document (basically I am attempting the `JTextPane` version of the HTML [a href="#link"] code). Right now, the code pretty much works, properly moving the caret to the correct line when the user selects a link. However, no matter what I seem to do, the very last link always throws a `IllegalArguementException`, saying I have a bad position of -1. I can't figure out why it keeps saying this.

Here is my code:

```
//JTextPane editor is instantiated above.

//searchTerm is the string that we are linking to in the text.
//I want the caret to move to where this text is in the JTextPane.

try
{
    int textPosition = text.indexOf(searchTerm);
    editor.setCaretPosition(textPosition);
    Rectangle bottom = editor.modelToView(textPosition);
    editor.scrollRectToVisible(bottom);
    editor.grabFocus();
}
catch (BadLocationException | IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Could not scroll to " + ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have already checked that "text" is in plain text form (not styled). So what am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to use the scrollRectToVisible or grabFocus method. When you use the setCaretPosition() method the text pane should scroll automatically. See [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for more information.

If you still have problems with this approach then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Maybe the `centerLineInScrollPane(...)` method from [Text Utilities](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) would be a better option for scrolling since the text will be at the center instead of the bottom.